# How to get field names in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, field

I need to find out the user privileges in mysql. When I look at `mysql.user` table there are bunch of fields that describes particular privileges with `enum('N','Y')` as value. 
My question is how to get all fields that have value `Y` for some concrete user? 
Here is the output for user columns:

```
mysql> show columns from mysql.user;
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Host                  | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| User                  | char(16)                          | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Password              | char(41)                          | NO   |     |         |       |
| Select_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Insert_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Update_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Delete_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Drop_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Reload_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Shutdown_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Process_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| File_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Grant_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| References_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Index_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_db_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Super_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Lock_tables_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Execute_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_slave_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Repl_client_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_view_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Show_view_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_routine_priv   | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Alter_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Create_user_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Event_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| Trigger_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N       |       |
| ssl_type              | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |         |       |
| ssl_cipher            | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_issuer           | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| x509_subject          | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| max_questions         | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_updates           | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_connections       | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| max_user_connections  | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `SHOW GRANTS FOR user@host`?

Comment: That's it!! Thanks, I'm not a mysql expert :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',
    IF(Select_priv = 'Y', 'Select', NULL),
    IF(Insert_priv = 'Y', 'Insert', NULL),
    ...
    IF(Trigger_priv = 'Y', 'Trigger', NULL)) AS Privileges
FROM mysql.user
WHERE User = 'someuser' AND Host = 'somehost'
```

Comment: That was my first approach but there is a lot of copy/paste work with this `IF` statements, and I'm wondering if there is some way to get rid of that typing

Comment: You could write dynamic SQL using the `iNFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` table to construct the query in a variable, then prepare and execute it.

Comment: Don't use copy-paste each line by hand. Paste the whole list of columns into an editor, and use a regexp replace to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can see all the privileges of an user like this

```
SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`user` WHERE `user`='your_user';
SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`db` WHERE `user`='your_user';
```

you can add in WHERE which field you like to be equal with 'Y'

Comment: He only wants to see the fields where the privilege is `Y`. This will show all the fields.

Comment: he can add  WHERE `user`='your_user' AND (Select_priv='Y' OR Insert_priv=Y) etc

Comment: For a specific user, he wants a list of ALL the enabled privileges.

Comment: In other words, he's trying to do something equivalent to what `SHOW GRANTS FOR <user>` does.

Comment: @Barmar  **for some concrete user?**

Comment: That means **for a specific user** he names in the query.

Comment: @Bamar you're right I've actually three users that I want to find out all enabled privileges